# Suppose that $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is the linear transformation that rotates a vector by 90°.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is the linear transformation
that rotates a vector by 90°.

> (a) What is the null space of T?
>
> (b) Is T one-to-one?
>
> (c) What is the range of T?
>
> (d) Is T onto?

Well I'm thinking this involved the Rotation Matrix. However, all of these things require a standard matrix $A$ to evaluate. How do I get a standard matrix from the rotation Matrix?

Comment: What are your thoughts about the question?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. If I were your instructor, I would tell you to look at the relevant definitions.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: The matrix for your transformation is $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{array}\right] $, assuming you mean counter-clockwise rotation.  Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: Yes thank you! How do I find that matrix though?

Comment: Protip for finding a matrix for any linear transformation: what happens to (1,0)?  That gives you your first column vector.  What happens to (0,1)?  That gives you the second column vector.  This works for any number of dimensions; if you wanted to do this for three dimensions, look at (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation (around the origin) being *linear* means geometrically that it takes triangles to triangles (if two sides of a triangle are $a$ and $b$ vectors, then the third is $a+b$), and it is invariant under scaling ($v\mapsto\lambda v$ for any $\lambda$)

(a) The nullspace contains exactly those vectors $v$ which go to $0$ (under the rotation now), that is, $Tv=0$. Can you find all such vectors?

(b) Suppose $Tv=Tw$, that is, by linearity, $T(v-w)=0$. Then, can we conclude that $v=w$?

(c) What vectors on the plane can arise as a rotated vector?

(d) Being onto means that the answer on (c) is '*all*' the vectors.

Answer (score 2):

hint - try to think of an operator that rotates the vectors by -90 degrees